How can i get the top smallest and top highest value for each row in pandas?
I have data that I have sorted, below is a sample of the data:
missing_values  count
0               51
3               1
12              12
13              1
15              1
16              1
21              1
35              2
36              3
40              1

I have the following code:
# Get the vount of each missing value
missing_value_count = missing_values.iloc[:, 0:1].value_counts().to_frame()
missing_value_count.sort_index(inplace=True)

missing_value_count.to_csv('question.csv')
    
missing_value_count.agg(lambda s: pd.Series([*s.nlargest().index, *s.nsmallest().index],
                       ['missing_values']),
                       axis='columns')

When I run the code I get the following error:
missing_value_count.agg(lambda s: pd.Series([*s.nlargest().index, *s.nsmallest().index],
                       ['missing_values']),
                       axis='columns')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[29], line 1
missing_value_count.agg(lambda s: pd.Series([*s.nlargest().index, *s.nsmallest().index],

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:9196 in aggregate
result = op.agg()

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:699 in agg
result = self.obj.apply(self.orig_f, axis, args=self.args, **self.kwargs)

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:9423 in apply
return op.apply().__finalize__(self, method="apply")

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:678 in apply
return self.apply_standard()

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:798 in apply_standard
results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:814 in apply_series_generator
results[i] = self.f(v)

  Cell In[29], line 1 in <lambda>
missing_value_count.agg(lambda s: pd.Series([*s.nlargest().index, *s.nsmallest().index],

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:500 in __init__
com.require_length_match(data, index)

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py:576 in require_length_match
raise ValueError(

ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (1)

I want to return the lowest value in missing_values with the highest values in count. So in the above data the result will be
missing_values      count
0                   51

How can I fix this part of my code to return the lowest value in missing_values with the hight=est count?
missing_value_count.agg(lambda s: pd.Series([*s.nlargest().index, *s.nsmallest().index],
                       ['missing_values']),
                       axis='columns')


Your example is ambiguous, do you want to give priority to the minimum "missing_values" or maximum "count"? Please demonstrate what happens if you had one row with 0/20 and one with 1/51

I would want the 1/51. I need the highest count with the lowest missing_value

df.sort_values(['count', 'missing_values'], ascending=[False, True]).iloc[:1]?

@mozway this is also a correct answer.

I believe the accepted answer is incomplete (not correct if you have more than one row with 51)

Like this?
result = missing_value_count[missing_value_count['count'] == missing_value_count['count'].max()]

where missing_value_count is the dataframe with the 2 columns you provided

One way to do is:
    df.agg({"missing_values": min, "count":max}).to_frame().T


No, this is not it. As you can see the output, I need the missing_values and count as pairs not seperate. In the output above missing_values 0 and count 51.
